# What does "dist-upgrade" mean in "apt-get upgrade"?

Tags: apt

`apt-get dist-upgrade` does not upgrade Linux distributions (though it does update kernels). From the manual on `apt-get`, the description of `dist-upgrade`:

```
dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
the general settings for individual packages.
```

That doesn't explain the `dist` part, so what does it mean or stand for?

Comment: Are you asking why it is named `dist-upgrade`?

Comment: @muru Yes, I am.

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get dist-upgrade` does not, by itself, upgrade the release of the distribution, yes. However, it can upgrade the release if `apt`'s sources point to the repositories of a newer releases. That is, if I changed the sources from those of `wheezy` to those of `jessie`, then I could upgrade the release from `wheezy` to `jessie` by using `dist-upgrade`. `upgrade` cannot do so, irrespective of the sources, since it cannot download new dependencies or remove conflicting ones.

This is how Debian is [upgraded from one release to the next](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrading-full).

Therefore, `dist` does stand for *distribution*, since it can, and does, upgrade the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

When you update packages inside a *stable* Debian release the packages won't change much (it is **stable** after all). You won't need `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

So changing dependencies like those mentioned in apt-gets manpage will only happen when you change the release (for example from *wheezy* to *jessie*), or when you use *testing* or *unstable* which are [rolling releases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release).

So yes, in a way `apt-get dist-upgrade` is usually used to update your distribution to the next release (or in the case of the rolling releases to their latest update).